# Retrieving object properties with relation to their parent categories

Tags: ios, realm

I am new to realm and iOS development so I apologize in advance if something isn’t explained properly or is just incorrect.

I have 2 Realm Object classes:

```
class Category: Object {

@objc dynamic var name: String = ""
@objc dynamic var color: String = ""
let trackers = List<Tracker>()
}
```

and

```
class Tracker: Object {

@objc dynamic var timeSegment: Int = 0
var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Category.self, property: 
"trackers")
}
```

I’m able to store new timeSegment properties consistently; however, the issue is that I cannot retrieve & display a collection of timeSegment values relating to their parentCategory. setting

```
var entries : Results<Tracker>?
```

produces all results for every category, which is the only result i'm able to pull so far after testing.

Any help is appreciated, and can follow up with any additional details. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call objects on your Realm object with a filter for fetching only results that match a predicate. The `realm` object in this code is an instance of the `Realm` class.

```
func getTrackersWithName(_ name: String) -> Results<Tracker> {
    return realm.objects(Tracker.self).filter("name = \"\(name)\"")
}
```

This tells Realm to fetch all objects that match the filter predicate. In this case, the filter predicate matches any object where the value of the "name" property matches the string that is passed into the method.

Comment: thank you, I incorporated this while adding an additional var in Tracker class that saves the selected category name, then sorted using that. it gave the same outcome anyway so problem solved, thanks!